# mv : get info from files to be overwritten

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there any "super" mv command out there which displays files info (size, date, etc.) when a destination file is to be overwritten with a source one ? This is, when  moving files around and two files happen to have the same name.

When this happens I need first to cancel the 'mv' command, 'ls' the destination folder, have a look at the file size, timestamp, etc., then compare it to the source one to see which one I want to keep, then resume the mv operation if I want to overwrite, otherwise just 'rm' the source one.

It would be great to get a similar behaviour as when this happens under a X session or Windows, so a decision can be taken without canceling the ongoing command.

Comment: You can write a script yourself to achieve your goal.

Comment: You run `mv` commands without looking at the target *before* actually running the command?

Comment: Yes, a script can do that.

Comment: If you only care about timestamps and overwrite only if newer, there is `mv -u`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: of course it can be done with a script, but sometimes they are already done and there is no need to reinvent the wheel every time

Comment: @AndrewHenle : I should have mentioned that I have mv aliased to mv -i, hence the prompt before overwritting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a very simple script wrapper, called for instance `smv` (for "super-move").

The script accepts exactly 2 arguments, the way the cmd `mv` would.  Make sure that it is executable, e.g. with `chmod 751 smv`, and ensure that the path corresponding to its location is in yr `PATH` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if ! [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: Include exactly 2 fully qualified file names as arguments, as in:" \
    "   $ smv /path/to/source /path/to/destination" "Abort."
elif [ -e "$2" ]; then
    (printf "\n%s\n\n" "Destination file exists."  && /usr/bin/stat "$2" ) 2>&1
    printf "\n" 
    read -p "Clobber it ? (Y/n):  " answer
    case "$answer" in
        N|n) echo "$1 not moved; $2 preserved. Abort.";  exit(11) ;;
        Y|y) \mv -f "$1" "$2" ;;
    esac
else
    printf "\n%s\n" "Destination file does not exist."
    \mv -i "$1" "$2"
    printf "%s\n"  "$1 was moved to $2."
fi
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, serves as a start to make a better display of stat command and get what I want !

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` or `--interactive` option to `mv` makes it prompt before overwriting. You can then easily copy the filename to another terminal and look at its metadata there.

Comment: I have that aliased already to my mv, i.e. "alias mv='mv -i' ". I should have mentioned this in my question